# Is Mediawiki markup context-sensitive?

Tags: parsing, mediawiki, grammar, context-free-grammar

There seems to be disagreement over whether MediaWiki markup (the markup language used to create and edit Wikipedia articles) is context-free or context-sensitive.

See [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User_talk:Kanor#Response_to_article_in_Meatball](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User_talk%3aKanor#Response_to_article_in_Meatball)

I would argue that it is obviously context-sensitive.  One example of this would be terminal characters in [wikimarkup lists](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User_talk%3aKanor#EBNF_rules_for_wiki_lists).  Lists are formed like:

```
* One thing
* Another thing
* Yet another thing
```

The *end* of a list item is indicated by a carriage return.

However, if the list is nested in, say a table or transclusion, then the *end* of a list item may either be a carriage return, or a table/transclusion terminal symbol.  For example, the following seems to be valid markup:

```
{{Infobox person
* One thing
* Another thing
* Yet another thing}}
```

However, a parser would need to keep track of the *context*, e.g. the fact that it is currently nested within a transclusion, when it encounters the `}}` symbol, instead of an end-line (carriage-return) character, when determining the *end* of the last list item.

So... how is this possibly *not* context-sensitive?

Comment: I wouldn't call it context-sensitive. maybe a state machine would be a better way of looking at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Context-sensitive" has a [precise formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar), and it does not appear to match your intuition. The grammar

```
S -> P | E
P -> '(' T '.' ')'
E -> '[' T '!' ']'
T -> <any context-free grammar fragment>
```

is context free (even regular, if `T` is regular), despite the fact that what comes after `T` (dot/exclamation mark) depends on the first character: There are no "context non-terminals" on the left hand side. Even arbitrary nesting isn't a problem:

```
S -> A | B
A -> '(' S ')'
B -> '[' S ']'
```

The parser has to remember which unmatched opening braces it has seen so far, but it does not need context in the sense of context-free/-sensitive grammars. These particular grammars aren't even *ambiguous* (again a formal term, also used in the Wiki user page you link to).
Context free does *not* mean "parser needs no working memory", or equivalently "parser can be restricted to look at every single token in complete isolation".